# How to use eclipse to write and execute PIG Latin

Tags: java, eclipse, apache-pig

I want to execute Pig scripts from eclipse in windows. I have followed [this link](http://wiki.apache.org/pig/EmbeddedPig). But it is not working. Is there any plugin required to do it? or only `pig.jar` is fine?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it works

```
Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
String pigCommand = "pig -f "+pigPath+"  //pigPath must be hdfs path.
Process proc = runTime.exec(pigCommand);
BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

String line = "";

while ( (line = bri.readLine()) != null);
while ( (line = bre.readLine()) != null);
```